# Back inactive flutter webveiw

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

i am not able to go back as page exits.Testing this code on Android studio flutter but going wrong somewhere.Any guidance help appreciated.This is my dart file

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
       void main() {
     runApp(MaterialApp(
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
       home: Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
               toolbarHeight:0,
           ),
         //appBar: null ,
         body: const WebView(
             initialUrl: "https://www.example.com",
             javascriptMode:JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           ) // WebView
       ), // Scaffold
     )); // MaterialApp
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebViewController](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html) to control page history: `goBack` and `goForward`.

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
  onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
    // store controller for later use
  },
```

Comment: Implementation says 
Future<void> goBack() {
  return _webViewPlatformController.goBack();
} but how to exactly add this widget